# How do I get others framed for murder?

Tags: party-hard

I've only just started playing Party Hard, but a few times now, I thought I was going to get busted by the cops for killing a bunch of people, but watched as the cop tackled an innocent party-goer and carried them away, while completely ignoring me.

It was awesome.

How do I make that happen? I feel like it wasn't just a random occurrence, but I'm not exactly sure how I caused it.